# Keep only functions in a Python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

Assume I have a Python script or module `bar.py` like this one

```py
# bar.py
some_variable = 1
print(some_variable)

def some_function():
  print('hello')
```

I need to create a copy of the script that only keeps the functions and does not contain any module-level code. For example, I would need to automatically create a copy of the script `bar_fun.py` that is defined as

```py
# bar_fun.py
def some_function():
  print('hello')
```

Any suggestion on how to do this?

Comment: With an editor.  Why would you do this?  How do you know the functions don't rely on any of the globals in the module?

Comment: Look for lines that start with `def `, and copy those lines and all following lines that begin with whitespace or a comment symbol.  Once you see a line that is not indented, stop copying (unless of course it is another `def`).

Comment: Do you actually need the exact function definitions on that other file? Or is this for "hiding" non-functions when importing your module `bar`? (This smells like the wrong solution to some other problem...)

Answer (score 0):

In this way you can find all callable objects in the `bar`:

```
>>> import bar
>>> list(filter(lambda item: callable(getattr(bar, item)), bar.__dir__()))
['f']
```

To copy them you can store all callable objects in a list, tuple or any other data structure that fits your need.

```
>>> list(map(lambda attr: getattr(bar, attr), filter(lambda item: callable(getattr(bar, item)), bar.__dir__())))
[<function f at 0x7f82d9aa6950>]
```

And if you need to store it into a file, you can use pickle:

```
>>> callables = list(map(lambda attr: getattr(bar, attr), filter(lambda item: callable(getattr(bar, item)), bar.__dir__())))
>>> import pickle
>>> file = open("functions", "wb")
>>> pickle.dump(callables, file)
```

Comment: ...but then how do you copy those callables to another file? (Which was the question.)

Comment: @GinoMempin I edited the question, but after all, I think the question is not clear.